# How to delete object from array that array contains dictionary

Tags: ios

I'm storing data in array like that..

```
while ([delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster next])
    {
    NSMutableDictionary *local_DICT = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSString *str_id = [delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster stringForColumn:@"category_id"];
    [local_DICT setObject:str_id forKey:@"category_id"];

    NSString *str_name = [delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster stringForColumn:@"category_name"];
    [local_DICT setObject:str_name forKey:@"category_name"];

    NSString *str_status = [delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster stringForColumn:@"status"];
    [local_DICT setObject:str_status forKey:@"status"];

    NSString *str_image = [delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster stringForColumn:@"image"];
    [local_DICT setObject:str_image forKey:@"image"];

    [category_array addObject:local_DICT];
    }
```

Now I want to delete 5th index value from array how to do this?

Comment: From the `category_array`?

Comment: [category_array removeObjectAtIndex:3]; it get crash.

Comment: Always a best practice - Check the size of `category_array` before removing item on a particular index. Also, from whatever code you have shown by far, you need to check how many times your `while` loop gets executed because that shall govern your array size.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's simply [`[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex:), however I also wanted to provide a more straight-forward implementation of your code:

```
NSDictionary *keys = @{ @"category_id", @"category_name", @"status", @"image" };
while ([delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster next])
{
    NSMutableDictionary *local_DICT = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (NSString *key in keys) {
        id value = [delegate_obj.Recordsetmaster stringForColumn:key];
        NSAssert(value, @"No value for '%@'", key);
        [local_DICT setObject:id forKey:key];
    }
    [category_array addObject:local_DICT];
}
```